# How to connect to an RDS database from Yii2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yii2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

I have deployed a Yii2 based app onto AWS Elastic Beanstalk, also I have created the RDS instance with a database (it already has tables) on Elastic Beanstalk. However I received this error: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"

All the files are uploaded correctly to the AWS instance.

The file /common/config/main-local.php has:

```
'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=RDS_HOSTNAME:RDS_PORT;dbname=RDS_DB_NAME',
            'username' => 'RDS_USERNAME',
            'password' => 'RDS_PASSWORD',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
```

What could be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want pass db information through environment variables. You may want to try to revise the code as below.

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host='.$_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME'].':'.$_SERVER['RDS_PORT'].';dbname='.$_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'username' => $_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'password' => $_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

You can reference http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html#rds-external-ec2classic in **To configure environment properties** section to configure your environment variables. Hope this works.

Comment: I put the above code and setup the variables through AWS, however I received this errror: "PDO Exception
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out". What could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I resolved the issue by changing to "all traffic" on EC2>Network&Security>Security Groups>Edit inbound rules

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 times your 'dsn' line and maybe the first one survives, so changing your config to this should work:

```
'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=RDS_HOSTNAME:RDS_PORT;dbname=RDS_DB_NAME',
            'username' => 'RDS_USERNAME',
            'password' => 'RDS_PASSWORD',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
```

(In addition I hope you are aware that you have to change RDS_* parameters :D)

Comment: What do you mean with: In addition I hope you are aware that you have to change RDS_* parameters. Thanks

Comment: I mean that you have to replace e.g RDS_HOSTNAME with some actual FQDN or IP, same for RDS_PORT RDS_DB_NAME, RDS_USERNAME and RDS_PASSWORD

Comment: I read that those were environment variables. I might misunderstood (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html). Thanks.

Comment: They may be environment variables but thats not how you read out those variables from your server. If you scroll down in your link, you will see how to fill your connection strings with those variables in PHP

Comment: I have understood that PDO is already installed on Yii2, is that right? Is the latter is truth the variables need to be setup like $dbhost = $_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME']; Is that the way to call an RDS database from Yii2? Thanks.

Comment: Changing the environment variables to strings, I have this error: PDO Exception SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out". Which is the right way to connect to an RDS database from Yii2? Thanks.