# PDO Exception SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out with Elastic Beanstalk and RDS on Yii2

Tags: amazon-web-services, yii2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

I have deployed a Yii2 based app onto AWS Elastic Beanstalk, also I have created the RDS instance with a database (it already has tables) on Elastic Beanstalk. All the files are uploaded correctly to the AWS instance.

The file /common/config/main-local.php has:

```
'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=myConnection_string:3306;myDB',
            'username' => 'myUsername',
            'password' => 'myPassword',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
```

What is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by changing to "all traffic" on EC2>Network&Security>Security Groups>Edit inbound rules.

Also I setup the variables on AWS and changed the script to:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host='.$_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME'].':'.$_SERVER['RDS_PORT'].';dbname='.$_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'username' => $_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'password' => $_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

This answer help me a lot: [How to connect to an RDS database from Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424106/how-to-connect-to-an-rds-database-from-yii2/44428076#44428076)

Comment: Allowing "all traffic" into to a database is very bad practise. Please don't do it.